# How to print consistent R visualizations of decomposed time series using autoplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, decomposition, autoplot

I have an R script that sometimes produces plots of decomposed time series one way and sometimes another way. I can't figure out if it's using two different autoplot() functions or what else could be making this happen. It is seemingly random: one week I get one format, the next week I get the other one.

I prefer the plot with the title "Decomposition of additive time series." Can anyone tell why running the same script gives me different results?

Thanks

```
library(pacman)
p_load(tidyverse, janitor, lubridate, forecast)

# import data
df <-
  clean_names(
    read_csv("data.csv")) %>% 
  mutate(date = mdy(date)) %>% 
  select(-dpb)

# create monthly df
df_monthly <- df %>%
  mutate(month = floor_date(date, unit = "month")) %>% 
  group_by(month) %>% 
  summarise(bbl = sum(bbl),
            rev = sum(rev)) %>% 
  mutate(dpb = rev/bbl) %>% 
  select(month, dpb)

# Decompose time series
t <- ts(data = df_monthly[,-1], start = c(2014, 1, 1), frequency = 12)

d <- decompose(t, type = "additive")

# Plot decomposed time series
p <- autoplot(d)

print(p)
```

I have tried specifying ggplot2::autoplot() and forecast::autoplot() thinking that would answer my question, but to no avail. Currently they are both producing the plot I don't want.

[don't want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJy1E.png)
[do want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5LGS.png)

Comment: Hi @dyork423. Please help make this a reproducible problem by sharing the contents of `data.csv`. Unless there's a concern about the data file itself, you can simply edit your question to include the output from `dput(df)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost certainly the differences arise because of the packages you have loaded. The code in your question should use the `autoplot.decomposed.ts()` function from the forecast package. But if you have loaded other packages, it is possible one of them has a similar function that is being used instead. In particular, the ggfortify package has an `autoplot.decomposed.ts()` function, so if you load ggfortify after you load forecast, you will get a different plot.

You can specify which one you want be prefixing the function with the package name. For example

```r
forecast:::autoplot.decomposed.ts(d)
```

Because the specific method is not exported, you need 3 dots, not 2 dots.